# Removing rows that have duplicate column values MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Suppose the first column is A and the second column is B in the picture below.
If there are duplicate values in column A, I want to remove the row which has the "*" appended to it in column B.

This would result in only the first row in the resultant table.

There are multiple rows like this in my MS Access query. How can I go about removing the appropriate ones in the design view?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
DELETE  DISTINCTROW T1.*
FROM    Table1 T1 INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT      FieldA
                FROM        Table1
                GROUP BY    FieldA
                HAVING      Count(FieldA)>1
            ) T2 ON T1.FieldA = T2.FieldA
WHERE       INSTR(T1.FieldB,"*")>0
```

Comment: That was perfection! Thanks alot!